# Google Analytics Data Upload Mime Type Error

Tags: php, google-analytics

Below is the code I am using in my data upload program.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
try {
$dailyUploadsFile = $analytics->management_dailyUploads->upload(
$_REQUEST['accountId'],             // your accountID
$_REQUEST['webPropertyId'],         // your web property ID
$_REQUEST['customDataSourceId'],    // your custom data source UID
$_REQUEST['datepicker'],            // date
$_REQUEST['appendNumber'],          // append number
'cost',                             // type of data
array(
  "reset" => $_REQUEST['reset'],
  "data" => file_get_contents_curl($_REQUEST['csvFile']),
  "mimeType" => 'application/octet-stream',
  "uploadType" => 'media'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
die('An error occured: ' . $e->getMessage()."\n");
}
}
```

Here is the error I am getting when I hit submit:

An error occured: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/34620205/webproperties/UA-34620205-1/customDataSources/P4Zlk69kSCOtVVIu7iFjqw/dailyUploads/2013-03-09/uploads?appendNumber=1&type=cost&reset=true&uploadType=media&key=AIzaSyDzvHpTNC_CKAnpyfnc1Vjwl_joE5hgBhc: (400) Media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported. Valid media types: [application/octet-stream]

Please help.

Comment: Can I expect an answer here? Please, its really urgent. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The `dailyUploads` [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/dailyUploads) for the Analytics API has been deprecated. It is recommend that you use the `uploads` [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData).

The following example should work for php given you have an authorized analytics service object.

```
$analytics->management_uploads->uploadData(
    '123456',
    'UA-123456-1',
    '122333444455555',
    array('data' => file_get_contents('example.csv'),
          'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
          'uploadType' => 'media'));
```